# Django User model -override, how to use login

Tags: python, django

I override Django User,and it worked, but i cannot use auth.authenticate to login

```
username = 'test'
password = '123'
user = auth.authenticate(username = username, password = password)
result = ''

if user:
    results = 'success'
    auth.login(request,user)
else:
    result = 'fail'
return render(request, 'login.html', locals())
```

this is my **model.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
   qq = models.CharField(max_length=20)

   class Meta:
      verbose_name = 'Myuser'
      def __str__(self):
         return self.username
```

and it return fail，how can i use login

Comment: test is create from admin  and i createsuperuser root  if i use root it worked

Comment: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html

Comment: Can you check if it is happening only for the users with the is_active flag set as False?

Answer (score 0):

```
user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
if user is not None:  #to check whether user is available or not?
# the password verified for the user
    if user.is_active:   
        results = 'success'
        auth.login(request,user)
    else:
        result = 'fail'
else:
# the authentication system was unable to verify the username and password
    print("The username and password were incorrect.")
```

Try  this one. and let me know it is working or not.